# javascript array check

Tags: javascript

I need to check one array content some items from another array.

as a example

```
var sData = {
    'template': 'template',
    'FOO': 'This is a paragraph'
};
```

How do I check if this array contain `'template'` value in `template` key?

Actually i need is this.

```
var sData2 = {
    'template': 'template New',
    'Boo': 'This is Not'
};
```

Now i need to check if sData2 contain `'template'` key and if it is there i need to replace sData array `'template'` value with sData2 array `'template'` value.

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object. It's not a search, it's an access. It's not JSON; it's a JS object. It has nothing to do with node; it's pure JS. Anyway, might want to read up on basics of JS objects. Here's one link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Don't change your question in mid-stream. If you have a different question, then close the old one and post a new one. It's a bit unreasonable to expect people to keep coming back to your question to see how it's changed and update their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(key in sData2) {
  if(typeof sData[key] !== 'undefined') {
    sData[key] = sData2[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: This key could be anything. Not only 'template'. ??